# string and subscript in label

Tags: string-manipulation

[image]

```
s = Import[
"Desktop/crack.xlsx", {"Data", 2, Range[1, 546], {1, 2, 4}}];
ListContourPlot[s, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
ColorFunction -> "Pastel", 
Contours -> Range[0.054, 0.27, (0.27 - 0.054)/10], 
FrameLabel -> {Subscript[X, 1], Subscript[X, 2]}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right], ColorFunction -> "Pastel",
PlotLabel -> Style["MLS" Subscript[u, 2]
OverTilde[\[Eta]] "=0.048%", FontSize -> 18]]
```

The label of this ouput has subscript and string. But I want the label show like the below. How to modify the Plotlabel command??

[image: I want the label like]

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `Row` to layout the text, and use `Spacer` command to adjust the spacing as needed

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Text@Style[
    TraditionalForm[
     Row[{"MLS", Spacer[5], Subscript[u, 2], Spacer[20], 
       OverTilde[\[Eta]] , Spacer[5], "= 0.048%"}]], FontSize -> 18], 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

Or, the way I would actually do it, is use Szhorvat nice [MaTex package](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX), like this

```
<< MaTeX`
label = MaTeX["\\text{MLS}\\, u_2 \\qquad \\tilde\\eta = 0.048\%", 
   Magnification -> 2];
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, PlotLabel -> label, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I personally prefer to just maintain labels as `Strings` like so: `TraditionalForm["MLS \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(u\), \(2\)]\)   \
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Eta]\), \(~\)]\)=0.048%"]`. The `InputForm` is quite ugly, but within the notebook one can use typesetting and it becomes a one-liner along the lines of `TraditionalForm["MLS u_2   ~\Eta=0.048%"]`

Answer (score 1):

Your output is formatted wrongly, because what you gave to `Style` is not a series of things to style, but a *multiplication* of its elements. Just evaluate the arguments on their own in your notebook to see the effect:

```
"MLS" Subscript[u, 2] OverTilde[\[Eta]] "=0.048%"
(* "=0.048%" "MLS" \!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Eta]\), \(~\)]\) Subscript[u, 2] *)
```

To get what you wanted, you could modify `PlotLabel` to

```
PlotLabel->TraditionalForm@
 Style[Row[{"MLS ", Subscript[u, 2], "\t", OverTilde[\[Eta]], 
  "=0.048%"}], FontSize -> 18]
```

[image]

Comment: fyi, I am not sure that using tab "\t" is recommend for spacing, as it might generate different space amount depending on the platform or some other system configuration. I think `Spacer[n]` is supposed to generate the exact space on all systems. (mac, linux, windows)

Comment: @Nasser: Well, `\t` works for me. ;)  But you are right, of course.